# Does phonegap support the html5 audio tag to play native audio file?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

Does phonegap support the html5 audio tag to play native mp3 file??

I want to develop an application using phonegap and play mp3 files on it.
It works when an online source is given in audio tag, like below

```
<audio> <!--works this way!!!--> 
<source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
```

but when I tried it with resident mp3 file in music folder, it didnt work. Like the snippet below

```
<audio><!--does not work this way :(--> 
<source src="music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
```

I also tried the following approaches to link the file in different assets directories, but it did not work

```
<audio><!--does not work this way:(--> 
<source src="android_asset/www/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>

<audio><!--does not work this way :(-->
<source src="/android_asset/www/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>

 <audio><!--does not work this way :(-->
<source src="file:///android_asset/www/music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
```

Then I tried the "phonegap media API" to make it work, but "phonegap media API" doesn't have progress bar and seek bar, so I would like to ask any idea to play the native audio file in phonegap.
THANKS

Comment: Possible duplicate,..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261532/get-absolute-path-to-assets-folder-in-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Given a `FileEntry` object, using `nativeURL` works fine for me. I do something like this:

```
<audio id='sound'></audio>
```

And from javascript:

```
var sound = $$("#sound");
sound.attr('src', myFileEntry.nativeURL);
sound[0].play();
```

Where `myFileEntry` is a variable containing a `FileEntry` object pointing to the audio file.